# What are some web-based knowledge-base solutions?

Tags: language-agnostic

I've used a WordPress blog and a Screwturn Wiki (at two separate jobs) to store private, company-specific KB info, but I'm looking for something that was created to be a knowledge base.  Specifically, I'd like to see:

- Free/low cost
- Simple method for users to subscribe to KB (or just sections) to get updates
- Ability to do page versioning/audit changes
- Limit access to certain pages for certain users
- Very simple method of posting/editing articles
- Very simple method of adding images to articles
- Excellent (fast, accurate) searching abilities
- Ability to rate and comment on articles

I liked using the Wordpress blog because it allowed me to use [Live Writer](http://get.live.com/) to add/edit articles and images, but it didn't have page versioning (that I could see).

I like using Screwturn wiki because of it's ability to track article versions, and I like it's clean look, but some non-technical people balk at the input and editing.

Comment: I know you asked this some time ago, but I am researching this issue right now.  I am interested in knowing what you ended up deciding to use?  I am considering KBPublisher as I want it to be on a LAMP server and self hosted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I second Luke's answer.

I can Recommend [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) and here is why:
I tested extensively many commercial and free Wiki based solutions. Not a single one is a winner on all accounts, including confluence. Let me try to make your quest a little shorter by summarizing what I have learned to be a pain and what is important:

- WYSIWYG is a most have feature for the Enterprise. A wiki without it, skip it
- Saying that, in reality, WYSIWYG doesn't work perfectly. It is more of a feature you must have to get the casual users not be afraid of the monster, and start using it. But you and anyone that wants to seriously create content, will very quickly get used to the wiki markup. it is faster and more reliable.
- You need good permissions controls (who can see, edit etc' a page). confluence has good, but I have my complaints (to complicated to be put here)
- You will want a good *export* feature. Most will give you a single page "PDF" export, but you need much more. For example, lets say you have an FAQ, you want to export the entire FAQ right? will that work?
- Macros: you want a community creating macros. You asked for example about the ability to **rate** pages, here is a [link](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/Rate+Macro) to a Macro for Confluence that lets you do that
- Structure: you want to be able to say that a page is a child of a different page, and be able to browse the data. The wikipedia model, of orphaned pages with no sturcture will not work in the Enterprise. (think FAQ, you want to have a hierarchy no?)
- Ability to *easily* attache picture to be embedded in the body of the page/article. In confluence, you need to upload the image and then can embed it, it could be a little better (CTR+V) but I guess this is easy enough for 80% of the users.

At the end of the day, remember that a Wiki will be valuable to you the more flexible it is. It needs to be a "blank" canvas, and your imagination is then used to "build" the application. In Confluence, I found 3 different "best practices" on how to create a FAQ. That means I can implement MANY things.

Some examples (I use my Wiki for)

- FAQ: any error, problem is logged. Used by PS and ENG. reduced internal support time dramatically
- Track account status: I implemetned sophisticated "dashboard" that you can see at a glance which customer is at what state, the software version they have, who in the company 'owns" the custoemr etc'
- Product: all documentation, installation instructions, the "what's new" etc
- Technical documentation, DB structure and what the tables mean
- HR: contact list, Document repository

My runner up (15 month ago) was free [Deki_Wiki](http://wiki.developer.mindtouch.com/Deki_Wiki), time has passed, so I don't know if this would be still my runner up.

good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I've also been investigating wiki software for use as a KB, but it is tricky to find something that is easy to use for non-technical people.  There are many wikis that attempt to provide WYSIWYG editing, but most of the software I've found generates nasty inefficient html markup from the WYSIWYG editor.

One notable exception to this is [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) which generates wiki syntax from a WYSIWYG editor. This still isn't perfect (show me a WYSIWYG editor that is) but is a pretty good compromise between retaining simple wiki syntax for those who like it and allowing non-technical users to contribute content.  The only problem is that Confluence isn't free ($1,200 for 25 user license).

Edit: I also tried DekiWiki and while the UI is nice it doesn't seem to be quite ready for primetime (suffers terribly from the bad WYSIWYG output disease mentioned above). Also seems like they lack direction as there are so many different ways of accomplishing the same task.

Answer (score 2):

[Cerberus](http://www.cerberusweb.com/) - it's more a full featured Help Desk/Issue Tracking system but it has a nice KB solution built in.  It can be free but they do have a low cost pay version that is also very good.

Answer (score 1):

I think Drupal is a very possible choice. It has a lot of built-in support for book-type information capturing.

And there is a rich collection of user generated modules which you can use to enhance the features.

I think it has almost all the features you ask for out of the box.
[Drupal CMS Benefits](http://drupal.org/features)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) for this purpose.  I've tried a number of other free and paid wikis (including [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/)) and have always been impressed with MediaWiki's simplicity and ease of use.

I have MediaWiki installed on a thumb drive (using [XAMPP](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp) from [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/)), which I use mostly as a personal knowledge base/code snippet repository. I can take it with me wherever I go, and view/edit it from any computer I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using a combination of

- TWiki
- OpenGrok for the codebase
- usenet
- LotusNotes based system

As long as there is a google search appliance pointed at these things I think it's ok to have any or many versions as long as people use them